# Problems trying to remove duplicates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to remove duplicate fields from a fata set in pandas, I have been working on several solutions for this problem and this is the only one that has given me the closest result to what I expected, but the problem is that for some reason a part of the data It is duplicating and I don't understand why.

This is the data:

```
{
  "codeId": "fc-5599",
  "financeInfo": [
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "totalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "totalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "totalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "totalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "totalReturn": 0.022425456852
    }, 
    {
      "date": "2022-02-28",
       "totalReturn": -0.0424735070051586,
       "financeInfoAttributes": [
       {
         "attributeId": "a-256",
         "value": "12.032791372796499"
       },
       {
       "attributeId": "a-257",
       "value": "9.975964795996589"
       },
       {
       "attributeId": "a-258",
       "value": "4.719852927810759"
       },
       {
       "attributeId": "a-259",
       "value": "4.18144793134823"
       },     
    ]
}
```

This is the code:

```
items = []
    for i in response_finance['results']:
        items.append(i)

    df = pd.DataFrame(items)

    df1 = df.loc[:, ['codeId', 'financeInfo']]
    for i in df1.columns:
        df1 = df1.explode(i)

    flat_df1 = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df1.to_json(orient="records")))

    df2 = flat_df1.loc[:, ['codeId', 'financeInfo.date',
                           'financeInfo.totalReturn', 'financeInfo.financeInfoAttributes']]
    for i in df2.columns:
        df2 = df2.explode(i)

    flat_df2 = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df2.to_json(orient="records")))

    result = pd.DataFrame(flat_df2)

    result.drop_duplicates(subset=None, inplace=True)

    result.to_csv('data.csv', index=True)
```

This is my output:

[image: Final result]

So in the end I have this always the first 3 columns are duplicated and the rest are not, but when I try to remove the duplicates I can't do it correctly, am I doing something else unifying the data sets or is my solution more complex than the problem itself?

Comment: IIUC you want to delete all rows where first three columns are the same, right ? then you need to define a subset in drop_duplicates instead of `None` . Or am I missing something?

Comment: came to say the same, please add subset for the first columns. Try: 
    `result.drop_duplicates(subset=['codeId', 'financeInfo.date', 'financeInfo.totalReturn'], inplace=True)` Otherwise, pandas looks at the whole row for a duplicates.

Comment: I already did it, I pass the id and the other columns to subset and anyway the result is the same, it does not eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: did you try to add subset exactly how @Nick has suggested ?

Comment: Yes, I do the exactly order, now I'm checking the pandas docs for this function and see if I miss another parameter or something.

Comment: could you add to your question the data of `print(results.to_dict())`?

Comment: Nick was right, now it works as it should, it was validating with a wrong file, thank you very much.